# How can I retrieve tracks by genre and year using Spotipy library?

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to extract data with the tracks from Spotify with a specific genre and year of release, I could do it in the https://developer.spotify.com/console/ so it would be "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=genre%3Arock%20AND%20year%3A2003&type=track&market=GB&limit=10&offset=5". BUT in the Python with the **Spotipy** package I am not quite sure how exactly I have to write it in the code, I tried this:

```
 genre = 'rock'
 year = '2003'
 tracks = sp.search(q='genre:' + genre and 'year:' + year, type='track',market='GB',limit=50, offset=0)
```

But it doesn't work (the **"and"** parameter doesn't work here and the results are random). If I put only year or genre it obviously works without any problem.

So, what should I use instead of "and" in the search query? (I couldn't find any example in [Spotipy documentation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/#), "&", "AND" etc also don't work)

[Here is the screenshot how it works in the Spotify console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVJeJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

from the [official doc](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#category-search) `&` should work. It has to be part of the spotify query though, otherwise python will try to interpret it. Could you try the following:

```
tracks = sp.search(q='genre:' + genre + '&year:' + year, type='track',market='GB',limit=50, offset=0)
```

Comment: thank you! '&year:' didn't work, but ' AND year:' did!